# Accessing cumulative values without initialising class with None

Tags: python

The functionality I'm looking for is to:

1. Call get_values() for each number of times.
2. A Metric object is initialised passing the date values in.
3. Find the datetime and then append it to the cumulative list.
4. Once the 'x in y' loop has **finished**, return the list.

The problem I've having is that I don't have any instance variables to pass through, which means I have to pass a 'None' object. I guess returning the Metric object is viable but I'd prefer if there was another option.

```
class Metric():
    cumulative_time = []

    def __init__(self, first_date, second_date):
        self.first_date = first_date
        self.second_date= second_date

    def get_datetime(self):
        datetime = self.first_date - self.second_date
        return datetime
    
    def append_cumulative_value(self, value):
        self.cumulative_time.append(value)

    def get_time_list(self):
        return self.cumulative_time

def get_values():
    first_date = ...
    second_date = ...
    metric = Metric(first_date, second_date)
    date = metric.get_datetime()
    metric.append_cumulative_value(date)


def main():
    for x in y:
        get_values()
        
    cumulative_time_list = Metric(None, None).get_time_list()
     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It's hard to know what objective is without more context. Are you timing something? It looks like you're iterating over y, but what are you trying to obtain? It looks like you're extending the class variable `cumulative_value` but that isn't an instance attribute.

Comment: Trying to get the list of times that so that averages can be taken on it. Iterating over y is just a placeholder to indicate that `get_values` can be run multiple times.

Comment: The methods that just use `cumulative_time` should be class methods, since they don't need anything from `self`.

Comment: Then you can use `Metric.get_time_list()`